# C++ and PHP common password hash standard

Tags: php, c++, security, cryptography, password-hash

I'm looking for a password hash standard that is easy to implement on php and c++. I know there is BCrypt but that really isn't that easy to implement on c++. Are there any hash algorithms that are easy to implement on both languages? I'm looking for this because I don't want my myBB forum cracked. They use md5 with salt which isn't really that good.
It doesn't protect me from being cracked. I know that. But if the forum is compromised I want a secure hash so they can't crack the passwords that easily.

Comment: You should change `encryption` to `hash`. Encrypted can be decrypted; hashed is one way.

Comment: Encryption/hashing doesn't defend you against your forum of being "cracked". It just prevents third parties from being able to see all the passwords once your data is compromised. (Which of course should always be the case)

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right is a good read.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877976/is-the-c-hash-function-reasonably-safe-for-passwords  - maybe even a possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks I'll read those two links. But Crypto++ isn't really easy to implement imo

Comment: Just wondering why the password-hashing is needed in two languages.

Comment: Im making a login system with PHP and a desktop application written in C++. I don't want intruders to capture traffic between the server and the client

Comment: 1. Do not encrypt the password on the client, that just becomes the password. 2. Use HTTPS, that will encrypt everything between the client and server.

Comment: My webhosting doesn't provide free ssl and it is too expensive for me

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: Just use libsodium on both ends, then `crypto_pwhash_str()` in C/C++ and `sodium_crypto_pwhash_str()` in PHP. This gives you Argon2id, which is better than bcrypt given appropriate cost factors.

Even if it's tempting to "implement" crypto yourself, you're must better off using a standard implementation such as libsodium, libcrypto (part of OpenSSL), etc.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest stronger algorithms such as SHA-256 or Blowfish. Even with MD5 salt it is weaker besides them.

However, whichever algorithm you use, use salt in your inputs. You can use both in php and c ++ effectively and easily.

Comment: SHA-256 is a general purpose algorithm and it is not supposed to be used for password hashing. It is too fast. But I'll look into Blowfish

Comment: Also I think that blowfish is an encryption/decryption method not a password hashing algorithm. Learn from my mistakes ^^